# function to check if anchor tags contain href attributes with 301

Tags: performance, php, regex

I made this function to test if the content has 301 redirections.. Please can you help me optimize it better because it's too slow

```
function contains_http_301_link($content, $current_site){
$pattern = '~<a(.*?)href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~';
$links = array();
// Check if there is a url in the content
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $urls)) {
    foreach($urls[0] as $url){
        // get external links

        if ( !strpos( $url, $current_site )) {                                   // Is an external link
            $vowels = array('"' ,"<a", " ", "href", "=", ">");
            $links[] = str_replace($vowels, "", $url);
        }
    }
}
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $_headers = @get_headers($link,1); 
    if($_headers && strpos( $_headers[0], '301')) { 
        return true;
    } 
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: How did you isolate the performance issue to this function? What do you consider `too slow`?

Comment: @pacmaninbw it works in the local but it gets crashed on production website due to timeout

Comment: This title does not describe what your code does.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/256759/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I have never attempted such a task, but I will assume that you entertained the cURL techniques (including `CURLOPT_NO_BODY` and `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE`) as suggest at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2964834/2943403) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427203/2943403).

As for parsing an html document, using regex may outperform a legitimate parser, but you might enjoy more accurate scaping if you use a DOM parser.

Since your focus is on performance, I'll [cringe] suggest regex to parse your html.

Your pattern `~<a(.*?)href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~` uses lazy quantifiers and this can slow things down a little.  Also, your `<a(.*?)href` will allow the matching of `<a data-href` and `<abbr href` -- which is not what you intend.

Your intention is to capture ONLY the url inside of the `href` attribute, so don't bother matching more than you need.  You can probably get away with a wordboundary after `a` and a space before `href`, then reset the fullstring match with `\K` to only retain the href's value.  If this isn't strong enough validation, then you could add a lookahead to confirm that the opening tag is completed properly.

- `~<a\b.*? href="\K[^"]+~` or
- `~<a\b.*? href="\K[^"]+(?=".*?>)~`

Either way, your code can skip the sanitizing step.  Thank goodness because `$vowels` contains data that are not all vowels.

`strpos()` can return `false` or `0` as the offset.  This means that you must not rely on the type juggled condition using merely `!`.  You must explicitly check for `false` or if you are on a php version that enjoys `str_contains()` -- that'll work.

I personally condemn the use of the "stfu operator" (`@`), but because I am not familiar with this task, I'll avoid calling it an abomination.

```
function contains_http_301_link(string $content, string $current_site): bool
{
    preg_match_all('~<a\b.*? href="\K[^"]+~', $content, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $url) {
        if (strpos($url, $current_site) !== false) {
            continue;
        }
        $headers = @get_headers($url, 1);
        if($headers && strpos($headers[0], '301') !== false) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

I could possibly include the `$current_site` filtration into the regex but it may do more harm than good.

---

If you were going to entertain (and benchmark) a DOM parser script, then perhaps use this:

```
function contains_http_301_link(string $content, string $current_site): bool
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument; 
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($xpath->query("//a[not(contains(@href, '$current_site'))]/@href") as $href) {
        $headers = @get_headers($href->nodeValue, 1);
        if($headers && strpos($headers[0], '301') !== false) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```